# Power Bi Issue :User not able to filter the data as the data is not showing in filters to select any category

Tags: power-bi-report-server

Suddenly our user is not able to see data to filter the categories in his powerBi report. When we try to open we are able to see the data in the report.

Source : opening in Data Analytics Portal by using chrome only.

Please kindly help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check

1. Whether data is filtered in any other page page that causes the data to be filtered in the page in which the category filter is shown.
2. Whether role based security is filtering out the category data
3. Whether bookmark has limited the data

Thanks.